# How to update my Pivot Table with addition field in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, updates, laravel-5.3

My table with eloquent relationship in laravel 5.3

```
     User
         --id
         --name
     Gallery
        --id
        --name
     Video
         --id
         --name
      Tags       *pivot table
         --id
         --gallery_id
         --video_id
         --user_id
         --created_at
         --deleted_at
```

Gallery Model:

```
public function videos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class,'tags','gallery_id','video_id')->withPivot('user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Video Model

```
public function galleries()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Gallery::class,'tags','video_id','gallery_id') ->withPivot('user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data['name]=$request->name;
    $video=Video::create($request->name);
    $video->galleries()->attach($request->gallery_id,['user_id' => Auth::id()]);
    return redirect('/video');
}
```

and its work is done,
But when update face a error (Illegal offset type)
Controller Update function

```
public function update(Request $request, Video $video)
{
  $data['name]=$request->name;
  $video->update($data);
  $video->galleries()->sync([$request->gallery_id=>['user_id'=>Auth::user()->id]]);
  return redirect('/video');
}
```

Anyone Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$video->update() is looking for an array, where as $request->name is likely a string.  Try the following.

```
public function update(Request $request, Video $video)
{
  $video->update(['name' => $request->name]);
  $gallery_id = $request->gallery_id;
  $video->galleries()->sync([$gallery_id => ['user_id'=>Auth::user()->id]]);
  return redirect('/video');
}
```

You are also mixing up your usage with Auth::id() and Auth::user()->id.  Is there a reason for this?

Edit:

Based on the comments, it looks like you were trying to use an array as the index in an array.  If you are always dealing with an array, you would have to change your code to look like this, which will build out the array in the proper format.

```
public function update(Request $request, Video $video)
    {
      $video->update(['name' => $request->name]);
      $sync_array = [];
      foreach($request->gallery_id as $gallery_id)
         $sync_array[$gallery_id] = ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id];

      $video->galleries()->sync($sync_array);
      return redirect('/video');
    }
```

If you sometimes have a string, and sometimes have an array, you will have to add a conditional in your code to check for this and make edits to your code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, here my video update table is ok, i already done by your suggest, but my tags table isn't update and show same error

Comment: Which line is the error being thrown on?  The update or the sync?

Comment: Error only the sync

Comment: Have you confirmed the value being sent in to $request->gallery_id?  Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key.  This would indicate that $gallery_id might not actually be an integer.

Comment: $request->gallery_is is a array 
output:   array:3 [▼
  0 => "18"
  1 => "19"
  2 => "20"
]

Comment: Okay, perfect.  That explains things then as an array can't be the index in an array.  Are you wanting to sync all 3 of those values?

Comment: When update some gallery id is new, some id is delete, or nothing
Just a single video multiple gallery tag with user_id

Comment: Yes sync 3 of those values

Comment: Error 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `tags` (`created_at`, `gallery_id`, `updated_at`, `video_id`, `0`) values (2016-12-04 04:44:58, 0, 2016-12-04 04:44:58, 28, 41))

Comment: Did you do it with my edit I made.  $sync_array[$gallery_id] =...?

Comment: What does the array output look like for $sync_array?

Comment: Try the code I have posted one more time.  I fixed an error shortly after posting the edit.  You maybe grab the example before I was able to apply the fix.

Comment: Array Output
`array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    18 => array:1 [▼
      "user_id" => 41
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    20 => array:1 [▼
      "user_id" => 41
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    21 => array:1 [▼
      "user_id" => 41
    ]
  ]
]`

Comment: How beautiful, its work, Thanks boss, Many many thanks for your support, 
Have you any problem Please tell me, i try to support

Comment: Many Many Thanks Again

Comment: Great!  My pleasure. :)